# Filter a field without searching through HTML tags in Directus

Tags: html, api, filtering, wysiwyg, directus

I've made a Collection with a WYSIWYG field in Directus.
How would I be able to filter the collection items with the API while excluding HTML tags?

**Example:**

Collection1 'custom_field' value: `<h1>Lorem Impsum<\/h1>`

Collection2 'custom_field' value: `<h1>The h1 tag is..<\/h1>`

API call ending with: `&filter[custom_field][like]=h1` returns both collections, while Collection1 should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this via the API, unless your project allows you to search for  `h1`  (spaces on either side), or something else that  only matches your direct query. Otherwise, one benefit of Directus is that you can query the database directly... so that should open up more possibilities.